# Why do my input groups have spacing like this

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I have this weird spacing in my input groups.  It happens in any of them I create unless i reduce the col spacing to smaller then the textbox.

here is my html

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cardNumber control-label col-md-3">CARD NUMBER</label>
                            <div class="input-group col-md-7">
                                <input name="number" type="tel" class="form-control cardNumber" size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Valid Card Number" autocomplete="cc-number" required autofocus />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">example.com</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: You have to show your CSS. Your HTML is good, I don't see any space between input and addon.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11:
https://jsfiddle.net/ayeucszb/
It's probably the rest of your HTML messing it up. Please give us something which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys, after inspecting it on the page I narrowed it down to a css item that .net puts in by default that sets the max width of a input.

Comment: In you first label you have control-label and col-md-3 inside the _for_ tag, those are classes: class="control-label col-md-3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like by default .net has this css in the site.css.  This was causing my problem.

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your second `input-group` div within a row and column too like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cardNumber control-label col-md-3">CARD NUMBER</label>
            <div class="input-group col-md-7">
                <input name="number" type="tel" class="form-control cardNumber" size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Valid Card Number" autocomplete="cc-number" required autofocus />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">example.com</span>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```